# How to construct an auxiliary function in this mean value theorem question?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f(x)$ be a real-valued function that is thrice differentiable on $[a,b]$, prove there exists a $\xi \in (a,b)$ such that $$f(b)=f(a)+\frac{1}{2}(b-a)(f'(a)+f'(b))-\frac{1}{12}(b-a)^3f'''(\xi)$$
I failed to establish a fine auxiliary function and the Taylor formula seems useless here. Please help me with your fabulous auxiliary function :)

Comment: You may draw a wrong conclusion.Consider $f(x)=x^2$ on $[a,b]=[0,1]$

Comment: If $a$ and $b$ are independent of each other, how are the coefficients of the first derivatives and abscissae just constant numbers?

Comment: @kellty sorry I've left out something and I just corrected it

Comment: @Reza yes, the original question got something wrong, I just corrected it

Comment: Isn't this trapezoidal rule?

Comment: Your equation should be $f(b) =f(a) +\dots$ instead of $f(a) =f(b) +\dots $. Other terms on right hand side are OK. I have edited to fix this typo.